# Междометие "ей-пра"

Tags: этимология

Ищу сведения о междометии *ей-пра*.
Значение, происхождение, современное употребление. Кто что знает, просьба откликнуться!

Comment: Ни  разу  не  слышал,  как  ни  странно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть, это сокращенное "ей богу - правда"?

Answer (score 2):

Да, я попытался поискать в Интернете -  безрезультатно. Возможно, это какое-то редкое междометие, встречающиеся в каких-нибудь говорах, ну, или, может быть, на малоизвестном сленге.

Comment: А  к  вам - то  как  оно  попало ?  Услышали  или  прочитали ?

Comment: Извините, Серж,  вопрос  не  вам,  к  Дерзкому  Grantum.

Comment: Есть в литературе упоминания :  
> Б. А. Лавренев. Сорок первый (1924)  
― Какой караван, что врешь? ― Ей-пра… провалиться, рыбья холера! Немаканы! ...
Ежели через три дня рыбалок не будет, ей-пра, пулю себе пущу!

>Л. Н. Сейфуллина. Виринея (1924)  
― Дядя Савелий, дядя! Избей, ей-пра, избей когда-нибудь! Грех от них и обида.

Наверное, мне из Лавренева и вспомнилось...

Comment: Ясно.  Наверно  было  популярно  какое - то  время.

Comment: Это — ответ или гадания?